# How is template function call ambiguity resolved?

Tags: c++

I want to make a function `conj` which will be applied only if the type of the argument is NOT `std::complex<T>`.  I could use `enable_if`, but do I need to?

If I have the following:

```
namespace{ 
    template<typename T> 
    T conj (T x) { 
        return x; 
    } 
}
```

And we already have in `std`

```
template<typename T> 
std::complex<T> conj (std::complex<T> x);
```

Will a call to `conj(z)` where `z` is `std::complex<double>` be resolved to the std version (since it is a 'better' match?)

Comment: I believe that is ok under ADL (a.k.a. Koenig Lookup). Have you tried it?

Comment: Why normal `conj` is in unnamed `namespace` ? Does it add any value ?

Comment: @iammiling: AFAIK, it means that any implementation file ends up with the function in their own unique namespace: `__one__::conj`, `__another__::conj` etc? No idea what would be the benefit of that here.

Answer (score 4):

> Will a call to conj (z) where z is std::complex be resolved to the std version (since it is a 'better' match?)

Yes. That is called [Argument Dependent-name Lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup). ADL in short, and is also known as **Koenig lookup**.

> I want to make a function conj which will be applied only if the type of the argument is NOT std::complex. I could use enable_if, but do I need to?

Nothing much. Define it inside a namespace, say `me`. And use qualified-name if the *type* of argument is not defined in the same namespace, or can use unqualified-name **if** the *type* of the argument is defined in the same namespace. In the latter case takes advantage of ADL. Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

namespace me
{ 
   template<typename T> 
    T conj (T x) 
    {
       std::cout << "me::conj" << std::endl;  
       return x; 
    } 
    struct A{};
}

struct B{};

int main() 
{
   std::complex<int> z(1,1);
   conj(z);  //calls std::conj due to ADL    

   me::A a; 
   conj(a); //unqualified-name : calls me::conj due to ADL

   me::conj(10); //qualified-name : ADL doesn't work with built-in types!

   B b; 
   me::conj(b); //qualified-name : B is not defined in 'me' namespace.
   return 0;
}
```

Demo : http://www.ideone.com/0HRXr

Comment: The comment `Enable ADL` is quite misleading, you cannot *enable* nor *disable* ADL. What that line does is avail of `me::conj` without qualification in the scope of `main`, i.e. it enables non-ADL lookup to find `me::conj` where the code only has `conj`

Comment: @David: I realized that. Therefore I modified my answer, accordingly.

Comment: I suppose somewhere `using me::conj;` would also be useful (just as the best way to call swap is `using std::swap; swap(a, b);)`?